# iOS7 home screen web app minimized shows a blank white screen

Tags: ios7, homescreen, minimized

I have a web app saved to homescreen in iOS7.

While its open and running, if i double tap the "home" button on the phone, the minimized display correctly shows a screen capture of the apps current state.

**However when switching to another app and then double tap "home" button to reveal the minimized app switcher, a blank, white screen is displayed instead.**

In other words, if a user has switched from my "homescreen" web app to another app and then attempts to switch back via the app switcher, a blank white screen is displayed as the minimized view.

**Is there any known way to fix this?** Is there a way to tell iOS7 to keep the first screen capture? I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution.

Comment: Any link can allow us to test it out ?

Comment: Have you set the load-screen for your web-app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per this link](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review), this is a limitation of ios 7 wherein the right screenshot is seen only if it is the currently active app.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is so unfortunate. I am certainly surprised that apple would let something like this go by the waste side.